# How to use array_agg in doctrine ORM Symfony 4.1?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

In my Symfony 4.1 project I have postgresql 9.6 as the DB. I am using doctrine ORM queries for DB transactions.
For one of transactions, Iam using array_agg() to get 2 or more rows as a single record. (Group concat does solve my purpose)
But it gives an error as array_agg() function not method.

Can any one tell how to use postgresql specific functions in doctrine?

Comment: Sound like you are misusing ORM. What is the exact purpose of that query? Is it reporting? Run plain SQL and wrap the result into an nice result class?  

How should ORM map the additional columns it's not aware of anyway?

Comment: Can you post your `Entity` here? Doctrine ORM aggregates data by default if you're using its methods such as `getQuery()` and `getResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not supported by ORM because an ORM seldom builds aggregated arrays. You are doing reporting here. SQL was made for that. No need for ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package which allows to use most of the postgresql functions for doctrine in Symfony

https://github.com/martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine/blob/master/docs/INTEGRATING-WITH-SYMFONY.md